# mongoose not saving my array after save()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

So i have thew following type of pattern:

```
board: {
id:
createdBy:
boardlist: [
{id, title: list1, cards: []}
{id, title: list2, cards: []}
]
```

I want to push a card inside the array of cards for specific list id

here is my code:

```
router.put("/add-card/:id", auth, boardAuth, async (req, res) => {
  const listId = req.params.id;

  const board = await Board.findOne({ _id: req.board._id });
  if (!board) return res.status(404).send("no such board");

  const list = await List.findOne({ _id: listId });
  if (!list) return res.status(404).send("List not found");

  const card = new Card({
    text: req.body.text,
  });

  list.cards.push(task);

  board.boardLists.map((list) => {
    if (listId.toString() === list._id.toString()) {
      list.cards.push(card);
    } else {
      null;
    }
  });
  await board.save();
  await list.save();
  res.send(board);
});
```

the problem is that when i do it its adding the card to that array one time and in the next time i do it its gone and replace the old one with new one.
if i push card "one" its will appear in the array when i send it, and in the next time i push "two" i dont see the last one "one" and its looks like i have there only 1 item.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get an error in the console? I suggest you do a `try/catch` block so we can catch errors and all.

```js
try {
  const board = await Board.findOne({ _id: req.board._id });
    if (!board) return res.status(404).send("no such board");

    const list = await List.findOne({ _id: listId });
    if (!list) return res.status(404).send("List not found");

    const card = new Card({
      text: req.body.text,
    });

    list.cards.push(task);

    board.boardLists.map((list) => {
      if (listId.toString() === list._id.toString()) {
        list.cards.push(card);
      } else {
        null;
      }
    });
    await board.save();
    await list.save();
    res.send(board);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

Comment: i dont get any error.
the card is added to the array only for one time, then if i add a new card i dont see the last one... there is allways 0 or 1 card

Comment: any idea someone?

Comment: Maybe you should check your model. If it is 0 or 1 then it is a model validation issue.